# Validate the file name and file type in type="file"

Tags: php, javascript, regex, if-statement

I have the following code to see if `type="file"` with the id `file` has been changed.

```
$('body').on('change', '#file', function() {
    // Do something
});
```

When I have choose a file I want to see if the file name and file type matches the requirements through this `if`:

```
if(/P[(0-9\.\JPG)]+|PICT[(0-9\.\JPG)]+/.test(theFile.name)) {
    // Do something
    // theFile.name contains the file name and file type in type="file" like this: my_file.jpg
}
```

The only problem with this `if` is that it passes all other files and not just the required. How can I make this to work properly?

Comment: I guess this is PHP? You should specify the language you're using.

Comment: What defines a valid file name?

Comment: `P1260407` and `PICT0843`. The digits are based on how many photos my camera have taken

Comment: what if it is .jpg not .JPG

Comment: @Paul That's true. But I leave my photos unharmed (no resizing or something like that). Some photos from the early 00's has been flipped though so they have `.jpg` and not `.JPG`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is invalid, or atleast it doesnt do what you want it to. You could stick it into regex101 and see why: http://regex101.com/r/hU9nD5

Use this regex instead: `/^(?:P|PICT)\d+\.\JPG$/` and if you want to support `.jpg` too, you can do: `/^(?:P|PICT)\d+\.(?:jpg|JPG)$/`, or if javascript supports it, inline modifiers `(?i)`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/vG7lC8

Comment: Many thanks! But I'm keep getting the following error message when I try the regex with a file that doesn't match the requirements in the regex: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(?:P|PICT)\d+\.\(?:jpg|JPG)$/: Unmatched ')'`. jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/ZtTqg/

Comment: Terribly sorry, I had made a typo. Try again :)

Comment: No worries :) Please test my code on jsFiddle. If I choose an invalid file after a reload of the page, I'm getting "wrong" one time. When I'm choose another invalid file I'm getting "wrong" 2 times. 3 times if I choose another invalid file and so on. This can't be because of the regex, right? If no, I'm opening a new question here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Frankly I don't see anything happening when I try your code. Regardless, the regex is now correct and would not cause you the trouble you are experiencing.

Comment: Then I have to thank you so much for your help with the regex :)